Show existence of polynomial that estimates $f$ and whose derivative estimates $f'$.
I'm self-studying from Abbott Analysis and am working on this question:
Assume $f$ has a continuous derivative on $[a,b]$. Show that there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $|f(x) - p(x)| < \epsilon$ and $|f'(x) - p'(x)|<\epsilon $
The solution manual gives a proof using the mean value theorem, which I can see now is the simplest way to prove this. However, I wrote another solution, and I wonder if it's correct/where I've gone wrong.
Let $\epsilon_n = 1/n$. By WAT, since $f'(x)$ is continuous, there exist polynomials $q_n(x)$ such that $|f'(x) - q_n(x) | < \epsilon_n$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Let $p_n(x)$ be the polynomial such that $p_n'(x) = q_n(x)$ and $p_n(a) = f(a)$. Since $p_n'(x) \to f'(x)$ uniformly, and $p_n(a)$ clearly converges to $f(a)$, then $p_n(x)$ converges to a function whose derivative is $f'(x)$, ie $f(x) + C$. But since we've fixed $p_n(a) = f(a)$, then we have that $p_n(x) \to f(x)$ uniformly.( This last statement is the one I'm least sure of)
Since we have both that $p_n'(x) \to f'(x)$ uniformly, then there exists $N_1$ such that $n>N_1$ then $|f(x) - p_{n}(x) | < \epsilon$. Similarly, there exists $N_2$ such that $n>N_2$ then $|f'(x) - p'_{n}(x)|<\epsilon $.  Taking $N=max\{N_1,N_2\}$, then for $n>N$, we have $p_n(x)$ that gives us the polynomial with the desired properties.
Have I made a mistake in this proof, or is this ok?
Thanks a ton!

Looks fine to me.

"Is my proof correct?" questions are not suitable here.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info.  You can ask about a single step that you are unsure about.  If you think you can, it would help to elaborate why you think that follows, and provide more justification and detail to justify why that follows.
